# Conditionally blink text

Tags: javascript, text, blink

Can anyone let me know how can i make it blink text based on if statement?

[image]

Sample:
if value 0 - NO BLINK
If not 0 - Should blink

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean `$('.blink')` instead of `$('blink')`?

Comment: if value 0 - NO BLINK
& Need to Blink if more than 0

Comment: What you mean with "If statement", Can you tell us when you want the text blinking and when not ?

Comment: When value is 0 (zero) no blink
if value not 0 (sample value 1) should need to blink

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `$('.blink')`, assuming you mean a class and not a tag name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function(){
      $('.blink').each(function(){
        $(this).css('visibility' , $(this).css('visibility') === 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden')
      });
    }, 250);
</script>
```

[JSFiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/2edLeav9/)

Comment: Also, remember to click the green checkmark if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the inline style, Since you are using jQuery, toggle will help you doing this. you can simply do it in this way.

Here is demo:

```js
 setInterval(function(){
      $('.blink').toggle();
    }, 250);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='blink'>Hello!</div>
<div class="blink">Testing again.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/tcy6a5kz/

```
//Line 21
if (blinkStatus == 1) {
    Blinker.start();
}
else {
    Blinker.stop();
}
```

At this line, you can change the if statement to whatever you want (true-like or false-like value).

You can get the `span` value like this:

```
// This will return the inner text of the span
// I expect this text as 0 or more. (number or text)
// No text in the span == 0
$('span.top-title').val();
```

So you can change my code at line 21:

```
//Line 21
if ($('span.top-title').val() == 1) {
    Blinker.start();
}
else {
    Blinker.stop();
}
```

**NOTE:** You need jQuery included to your site to run this code. Everything starting with `'$'` is jQuery object and cannot operate without jQuery library.

In case you do not have jQuery. You can include it in your HTML:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

This script must be included **before** the scripts that uses jQuery. (in most cases it's included at the `<head>` tag of the HTML. I'm not sure, but I think the "blog service providers" ignoring script definitions in the blog posts.

Comment: Still as it is No luck :(

Comment: If you tell me where you trying to include this feature, I can try to work it out. I mean... You have a site? Or may be, you are trying to made it in a blog post? Which blog provider you're using if it is a blog? More info?

Comment: http://i1205.photobucket.com/albums/bb426/krishnaa5/Untitled-2.png 
you can see that from above image - showing 0
if value more than 0 - need to blink
------------ -------------
               <div><span class="top-title">
                0
                  </span></div>

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too old, but it might help someone searching for this.
I figure it out myself and I know that this is not the best solution.

```
<div class="blink1">
<span><asp:Label runat="server" Text="Label" ID="inprogress"></asp:Label></span> 
</div>
<div class="blink2"><span><asp:Label runat="server" Text="Label" ID="behindsched"></asp:Label></span>
</div>


    <script>
var in_progress = parseInt(documentElementById("<%=inprogress.ClientID%>").innerHTML);
var behind_sched = parseInt(documentElementById("<%=behindsched.ClientID%>").innerHTML);
  
    var blinkfunc1 = function(){
        $('.blink1').toggle();
        }
    var blinkfunc2 = function(){
        $('.blink2').toggle();
        }
    var blinkspeed = 550;
$(document).ready(function{
    if(in_progress > 0){
        setInterval(blinkfunc1, blinkspeed);
        }
    if(behind_sched > 0){
        setInterval(blinkfunc2, blinkspeed);
        }
});
    </script>
```

Make sure you don't forget this into your head tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```